# Messaging Plugin Cakephp

Tags: cakephp, messaging

I tried to use the plugin `skitle/CakePHP-Messaging-Plugin` but I did not find documentation describing how to install and use it. I have the the same question for the `Messages-Zuha-Cakephp-Plugin-master`.

Answer (score 0):

Easily found with a search engine.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/plugins.html

Next time look harder before posting a question.

Please read ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)